# Finding Gravitational Force b/w 2 People

Tags: newtonian-gravity, mass, earth

I just need some clarification. The question is:

> What is the gravitational force between two 100 kg people standing 1 m apart, and how does this compare with the gravitational force of either of them relative to Earth?

I'm guessing the formula to use here is Newton's Law of Gravitation. So, I'd use $M_1, M_2$ = 100 kg, and use $1$m as $r$, right? And to find one of the people's force relative to the Earth, what value do I use for $r$? Isn't the distance between the Earth and any person almost negligible? Thank you.

Comment: You should use the radius of earth.

Comment: Or just use $W=mg$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a spherical object the gravitational field is the same as if all the mass was at the centre of the object. This is known as [Newton's shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem). So when we talk about the distance $r$ from the Earth in the law of gravitation we mean the distance from the centre of the Earth.

Strictly speaking this isn't true since the Earth is an oblate spheroid not a sphere, but in practice the Earth is close enough to spherical for this to be an excellent approximation.

For two people around $2$m tall and $1$m apart the assumption that the people are spherical is obviously a poor one and will not give the correct gravitational field. However doing this calculation properly is something you aren't taught until you start doing a physics degree, so I would guess that you are also supposed to assume the people are spherical and use the distance from their centre of mass. This will give you an order of magnitude estimate of the force, which is probably close enough to show how small it is compared to the force between the people and the Earth.

Comment: How would one calculate this properly (assuming one has a physics degree)?

Comment: @mikey: choose one of the people (either will do) and divide that person into infinitesimal volume elements. For each volume element calculate the force due to similar infinitesimal elements in the other person and integrate to get the total force on that element. Finally integrate again to sum up the total force over the whole body. Messy, but straightforward in principle.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Perhaps I should clarify. For planetary bodies, spheres are a good approximation. I meant to ask how one would parametrize the shape of a human? My guess is summing volume elements of many much smaller shapes.

Comment: @mikey If you wantered to parameterise it you'd probably express the mass distribution as a sum of multipoles. The monopole is your spherical approximation and the quadrupole describes how long and thin you are. Higher multipoles give an increasingly accurate description of your shape and gravitational force.

Answer (score 0):

$$F = \frac{G m_1 m_2}{ r^2}$$

where  $r$  is the distance between the center of gravity of the individuals.

$$
F = \frac{6.67\cdot10^{-11} \text N \cdot { \text m^2/ \text k\text g^2}\times 100~\text k \text g \times 100~\text k\text g}{1~\text m^2}=6.67\cdot10^{-7} \text N
$$

The gravitation force of one of them with the earth would be about 1000 N.

Comment: Math can be typeset in a readable form by using MathJax. The main elements can be easily learned on tutorials on-line.